# Can I delete a field in awk?

Tags: awk, sed, cut

This is `test.txt`:

```
0x01,0xDF,0x93,0x65,0xF8
0x01,0xB0,0x01,0x03,0x02,0x00,0x64,0x06,0x01,0xB0
0x01,0xB2,0x00,0x76
```

If I run
`awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{$2="";print $0}' test.txt`
the result is:

```
0x01,,0x93,0x65,0xF8
0x01,,0x01,0x03,0x02,0x00,0x64,0x06,0x01,0xB0
0x01,,0x00,0x76
```

The $2 wasn't deleted, it just became empty.
I hope, when printing $0, that the result is:

```
0x01,0x93,0x65,0xF8
0x01,0x01,0x03,0x02,0x00,0x64,0x06,0x01,0xB0
0x01,0x00,0x76
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe simplest would be to use `sub` function to replace first occurrence of continuous `,,`(which are getting created after you made 2nd field NULL) with single `,`. But this assumes that you don't have any commas in between field values.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$2="";sub(/,,/,",");print $0}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** OR you could use `match` function to catch regex from first comma to next comma's occurrence and get before and after line of matched string.

```
awk '
match($0,/,[^,]*,/){
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1)","substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 27):

All the existing solutions are good though this is actually a tailor made job for `cut`:

```sh
cut -d, -f 1,3- file

0x01,0x93,0x65,0xF8
0x01,0x01,0x03,0x02,0x00,0x64,0x06,0x01,0xB0
0x01,0x00,0x76
```

If you want to remove 3rd field then use:

```
cut -d, -f 1,2,4- file
```

To remove 4th field use:

```
cut -d, -f 1-3,5- file
```

Comment: The following is even better for removing the 2nd field, especially when there are many fields: `cut --complement -d, -f2 file`

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit heavy-handed, but this moves each field after field 2 down a place, and then changes `NF` so the unwanted field is not present:

```sh
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ for (i = 2; i < NF; i++) $i = $(i+1); NF--; print }' test.txt
0x01,0x93,0x65,0xF8
0x01,0x01,0x03,0x02,0x00,0x64,0x06,0x01
0x01,0x00,0x76
$
```

Tested with both GNU Awk 4.1.3 and BSD Awk ("`awk version 20070501`" on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 — don't ask; it frustrates me too, but sometimes employers are not very good at forward thinking).  Setting `NF` may or may not work on older versions of Awk — I was a little surprised it *did* work, but the surprise was a pleasant one, for a change.

Answer (score 3):

If Awk is not an absolute requirement, and the input is indeed as trivial as in your example, `sed` might be a simpler solution.

```sh
sed 's/,[^,]*//' test.txt
```

This is especially elegant if you want to remove the second field.  A more generic approach to remove, the *n*th field would require you to put in a regex which matches the first *n* - 1 followed by the *n*th, then replace that with just the the first *n* - 1.

So for *n* = 4 you'd have

```sh
sed 's/\([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,\)[^,]*,/\1/' test.txt
```

or more generally, if your `sed` dialect understands braces for specifying repetitions

```
sed 's/\(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}\)[^,]*,/\1/' test.txt
```

Some `sed` dialects allow you to lose all those pesky backslashes with an option like `-r` or `-E` but again, this is not universally supported or portable.

In case it's not obvious, `[^,]` matches a single character which is not (newline or) comma; and `\1` recalls the text from first parenthesized match (back reference; `\2` recalls the second, etc).

Also, this is completely unsuitable for escaped or quoted fields (though I'm not saying it can't be done).  Every comma acts as a field separator, no matter what.

Comment: The `\n` is not entirely portable, but yeah.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed you can add a number modifier to substitute nth match of non-comma characters followed by comma:

```
sed -E 's/[^,]*,//2' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk in a regex-free way, with the option to choose which line will be deleted:

```
awk '{ col = 2; n = split($0,arr,","); line = ""; for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) line = line ( i == col ? "" : ( line == "" ? "" : ","  ) arr[i] ); print line }' test.txt
```

Step by step:

```
{
col = 2    # defines which column will be deleted
n = split($0,arr,",")    # each line is split into an array
                         # n is the number of elements in the array

line = ""     # this will be the new line

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)   # roaming through all elements in the array
    line = line ( i == col ? "" : ( line == "" ? "" : "," ) arr[i] )
    # appends a comma (except if line is still empty)
    # and the current array element to the line (except when on the selected column)

print line    # prints line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Commenting on [the first solution of @RavinderSingh13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65283981/1549818) using sub() function:

> ```
> awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$2="";sub(/,,/,",");print $0}' Input_file
> ```

The `gnu-awk` manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html

> It is important to note that making an assignment to an existing field changes the value of $0 but does not change the value of NF, even when you assign the empty string to a field." (4.4 Changing the Contents of a Field)

So, following the first solution of RavinderSingh13 but without  using, in this case,`sub()` "The field is still there; it just has an empty value, delimited by the two colons":

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {$2="";print $0}' file 
0x01,,0x93,0x65,0xF8
0x01,,0x01,0x03,0x02,0x00,0x64,0x06,0x01,0xB0
0x01,,0x00,0x76
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment on the mentioned answer and perhaps incorporated into an edit!

Comment: Yes, probably, but I think it's  important to know that, which is a general concept.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
awk -F, '
{
    regex = "^"$1","$2
    sub(regex, $1, $0);
    print $0;
}'
```

or one line code:
`awk -F, '{regex="^"$1","$2;sub(regex, $1, $0);print $0;}' test.txt`

I found that OFS="," was not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

You can just pipe the output to another sed and squeeze the delimiters.

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{$2=""}1 ' edward.txt  | sed 's/,,/,/g'
0x01,0x93,0x65,0xF8
0x01,0x01,0x03,0x02,0x00,0x64,0x06,0x01,0xB0
0x01,0x00,0x76
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way, let `file.txt` content be:

```
0x01,0xDF,0x93,0x65,0xF8
0x01,0xB0,0x01,0x03,0x02,0x00,0x64,0x06,0x01,0xB0
0x01,0xB2,0x00,0x76
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=""}{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=1){$i="," $i};$2="";print}' file.txt
```

output

```
0x01,0x93,0x65,0xF8
0x01,0x01,0x03,0x02,0x00,0x64,0x06,0x01,0xB0
0x01,0x00,0x76
```

Explanation: I set `OFS` to nothing (empty string), then for 2nd and following column I add `,` at start. Finally I set what is now comma and value to nothing. Keep in mind this solution would need rework if you wish to remove 1st column.